# Inverting the RMS-AM inequality

Tags: inequality

The RMS-AM inequality states that for positive real numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n$,
$$AM=\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}\leq\sqrt{\frac{x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2}{n}}=RMS.$$
For two positive numbers $x_1,x_2$, the inequality can be inferred geometrically from the diagram below.

[image]

Unless I'm mistaken, the picture also seems to imply that for two positive numbers $x_1,x_2$,

$$RMS^2\leq 2\cdot AM^2$$

so that 
$$AM=\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sqrt{\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2}{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}RMS.$$

Is anyone aware of how this might generalise for more than two numbers?

Comment: i think this is what you need http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/gwan01200422828.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-negative numbers $x_1,\ldots, x_n$
$$
 x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2 \le (x_1 +  \ldots + x_n)^2
$$
holds, as can be seen by expanding the right-hand side. It follows that
$$
 RMS^2 \le n \cdot AM^2 
$$
or
$$
 AM \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt n} RMS
$$
which generalizes your result for $n=2$.

The factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$ is best possible because
equality holds if $x_1 > 0, x_2 = \ldots x_n = 0$.

Comment: Oh yes. Of course! Thanks.